# running junit crashes eclipse, java exit =1

Tags: eclipse, junit

**My eclipse is crashing everytime i try to run even a single junit. I tried multiple switches found while searching for the problem**

```
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/CPPASTFunctionDeclarator,postAccept
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPSemantics,declaredBefore
```

1. Tried playing with memory sizes also.
2. Tried giving -vm arg for    specifying jdk javaw

Error log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000fdd032d7, pid=288, tid=512
#
# JRE version: 7.0_05-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.1-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [LPK.dll+0x32d7]  LpkGetTextExtentExPoint+0x14b7
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000022cd000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=512, stack(0x0000000002490000,0x0000000002590000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000020

R
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(JJIJJ)J
J  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(JJIJJ)J
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.callWindowProc(JIJJ)J+852
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(JIJJ)J
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.windowProc(JIJJ)J+98
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(JJJJ)J
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowTextW(J[C)Z+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowText(JLorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/TCHAR;)Z+21
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.setText(Ljava/lang/String;)V+109
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.CounterPanel.setErrorValue(I)V+8
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.TestRunnerViewPart.refreshCounters()V+117
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.TestRunnerViewPart.processChangesInUI()V+16
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.TestRunnerViewPart.access$12(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/ui/TestRunnerViewPart;)V+1
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.TestRunnerViewPart$16.run()V+4
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+121
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+91
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+64
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.TestRunnerViewPart.postSyncRunnable(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.TestRunnerViewPart.postSyncProcessChanges()V+9
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.TestRunnerViewPart.stopUpdateJobs()V+48
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.TestRunnerViewPart.setActiveTestRunSession(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/model/TestRunSession;)Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/model/TestRunSession;+267
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.TestRunnerViewPart.access$2(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/ui/TestRunnerViewPart;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/model/TestRunSession;)Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/model/TestRunSession;+2
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.TestRunnerViewPart$3.run()V+97
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run()V+11
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+29
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+5
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+91
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Lorg/eclipse/jface/window/Window$IExceptionHandler;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;)V+9
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI()I+555
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/Workbench;)I+1
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run()V+55
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+99
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

  eden space 93952K, 32% used [0x00000000f8000000,0x00000000f9dacdb8,0x00000000fdbc0000)
  from space 17792K, 99% used [0x00000000fdbc0000,0x00000000fed18610,0x00000000fed20000)
  to   space 19328K, 0% used [0x00000000fed20000,0x00000000fed20000,0x0000000000000000)
 ParOldGen       total 104192K, used 74689K [0x00000000e8000000, 0x00000000ee5c0000, 0x00000000f8000000)
  object space 104192K, 71% used [0x00000000e8000000,0x00000000ec8f0460,0x00000000ee5c0000)
 PSPermGen       total 102848K, used 62194K [0x00000000d8000000, 0x00000000de470000, 0x00000000e8000000)
  object space 102848K, 60% used [0x00000000d8000000,0x00000000dbcbc880,0x00000000de470000)
Event: 101.873 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=23 (full 3):
 PSYoungGen      total 104832K, used 2144K [0x00000000f8000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000)
  eden space 85504K, 0% used [0x00000000f8000000,0x00000000f8000000,0x00000000fd380000)
  from space 19328K, 11% used [0x00000000fed20000,0x00000000fef38000,0x0000000000000000)
  to   space 22784K, 0% used [0x00000000fd380000,0x00000000fd380000,0x00000000fe9c0000)
 ParOldGen       total 104192K, used 79317K [0x00000000e8000000, 0x00000000ee5c0000, 0x00000000f8000000)
  object space 104192K, 76% used [0x00000000e8000000,0x00000000ecd75428,0x00000000ee5c0000)
 PSPermGen       total 102848K, used 62194K [0x00000000d8000000, 0x00000000de470000, 0x00000000e8000000)
  object space 102848K, 60% used [0x00000000d8000000,0x00000000dbcbc880,0x00000000de470000)
}
Event: 101.873 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=24 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 104832K, used 2144K [0x00000000f8000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000)
  eden space 85504K, 0% used [0x00000000f8000000,0x00000000f8000000,0x00000000fd380000)
  from space 19328K, 11% used [0x00000000fed20000,0x00000000fef38000,0x0000000000000000)
  to   space 22784K, 0% used [0x00000000fd380000,0x00000000fd380000,0x00000000fe9c0000)
 ParOldGen       total 104192K, used 79317K [0x00000000e8000000, 0x00000000ee5c0000, 0x00000000f8000000)
  object space 104192K, 76% used [0x00000000e8000000,0x00000000ecd75428,0x00000000ee5c0000)
 PSPermGen       total 102848K, used 62194K [0x00000000d8000000, 0x00000000de470000, 0x00000000e8000000)
  object space 102848K, 60% used [0x00000000d8000000,0x00000000dbcbc880,0x00000000de470000)
Event: 102.121 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=24 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 104832K, used 0K [0x00000000f8000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000)
  eden space 85504K, 0% used [0x00000000f8000000,0x00000000f8000000,0x00000000fd380000)
  from space 19328K, 0% used [0x00000000fed20000,0x00000000fed20000,0x0000000000000000)
  to   space 22784K, 0% used [0x00000000fd380000,0x00000000fd380000,0x00000000fe9c0000)
 ParOldGen       total 104192K, used 33208K [0x00000000e8000000, 0x00000000ee5c0000, 0x00000000f8000000)
  object space 104192K, 31% used [0x00000000e8000000,0x00000000ea06e088,0x00000000ee5c0000)
 PSPermGen       total 104576K, used 62193K [0x00000000d8000000, 0x00000000de620000, 0x00000000e8000000)
  object space 104576K, 59% used [0x00000000d8000000,0x00000000dbcbc6d8,0x00000000de620000)
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 104.278 Thread 0x000000000b1cb000 Uncommon trap -58 fr.pc 0x00000000029d2f34
Event: 104.839 Thread 0x000000000b1cb000 Uncommon trap -58 fr.pc 0x00000000029f3710
Event: 104.839 Thread 0x000000000b1cb000 Uncommon trap -58 fr.pc 0x00000000029f37b4
Event: 105.275 Thread 0x000000000b1cb000 Uncommon trap -58 fr.pc 0x00000000029f3710
Event: 105.854 Thread 0x00000000022cd000 Uncommon trap -12 fr.pc 0x000000000293e8b8
Event: 106.024 Thread 0x000000000b1cb000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002a2d250
Event: 107.073 Thread 0x00000000022cd000 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x000000000284ca68
Event: 107.995 Thread 0x000000000a9af800 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x000000000284e678
Event: 107.998 Thread 0x000000000a9af800 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x000000000284d9cc
Event: 108.068 Thread 0x000000000b1cb000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002a2d250

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 105.835 Thread 0x00000000022cd000 Threw 0x00000000fafce5f0 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u5\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715
Event: 105.906 Thread 0x00000000022cd000 Threw 0x00000000fb15df98 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u5\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715
Event: 106.992 Thread 0x00000000022cd000 Threw 0x00000000fb2e1cd0 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u5\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715
Event: 107.237 Thread 0x00000000022cd000 Threw 0x00000000fba5efd8 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u5\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715


Events (10 events):
Event: 108.520 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 108.520 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 108.521 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 108.521 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 108.697 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 108.697 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 108.727 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 108.728 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 108.728 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 108.728 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000003fea0000 - 0x000000003fed4000     C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
0x0000000077b60000 - 0x0000000077d0c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077940000 - 0x0000000077a5f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x00000000fd610000 - 0x00000000fd67c000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00000000fd870000 - 0x00000000fd94b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00000000ff100000 - 0x00000000ff19f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00000000ff1a0000 - 0x00000000ff1bf000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x00000000ff210000 - 0x00000000ff33e000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000077a60000 - 0x0000000077b5a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x00000000fe020000 - 0x00000000fe087000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00000000fdd00000 - 0x00000000fdd0e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x00000000ff030000 - 0x00000000ff0fa000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x00000000fb990000 - 0x00000000fbb84000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16661_none_fa62ad231704eab7\COMCTL32.dll
0x00000000fdd10000 - 0x00000000fdd81000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00000000fd950000 - 0x00000000fd97e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x00000000fdf10000 - 0x00000000fe019000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000000006ad60000 - 0x000000006ae31000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000006a640000 - 0x000000006ad5a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00000000fc960000 - 0x00000000fc969000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00000000ff1c0000 - 0x00000000ff20d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x00000000fdc50000 - 0x00000000fdc58000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x00000000fbd20000 - 0x00000000fbd5b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000077d30000 - 0x0000000077d37000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000073d40000 - 0x0000000073d4f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006bf30000 - 0x000000006bf58000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x000000006c470000 - 0x000000006c485000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
0x00000000fcd30000 - 0x00000000fcd47000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x00000000fc910000 - 0x00000000fc957000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x00000000fc970000 - 0x00000000fc98e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x00000000fd4a0000 - 0x00000000fd4af000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x00000000fd3d0000 - 0x00000000fd3df000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000000006bf70000 - 0x000000006bf89000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\net.dll
0x00000000fccd0000 - 0x00000000fcd24000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00000000fccc0000 - 0x00000000fccc7000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x00000000faf60000 - 0x00000000faf75000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x00000000fcb50000 - 0x00000000fcbab000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x00000000f9080000 - 0x00000000f908b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x00000000f9060000 - 0x00000000f9075000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x00000000f9040000 - 0x00000000f9059000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x00000000f8fd0000 - 0x00000000f8fe0000     C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x00000000723a0000 - 0x00000000723ce000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x00000000fc510000 - 0x00000000fc517000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x00000000fa7f0000 - 0x00000000fa817000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x00000000fa7e0000 - 0x00000000fa7eb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x00000000f87b0000 - 0x00000000f87b8000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x00000000fa620000 - 0x00000000fa673000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000000006bf10000 - 0x000000006bf21000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000072000000 - 0x0000000072012000     C:\Users\ASHISH\Downloads\Technology\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222\eclipse_1312.dll
0x00000000fc440000 - 0x00000000fc44c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x00000000fbcc0000 - 0x00000000fbd16000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x0000000010000000 - 0x0000000010065000     C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\btmmhook.dll
0x00000000fe090000 - 0x00000000fee17000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00000000fee20000 - 0x00000000ff022000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x00000000fde30000 - 0x00000000fdf07000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00000000fdb60000 - 0x00000000fdbf9000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x0000000007780000 - 0x000000000781b000     C:\Users\ASHISH\Downloads\Technology\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\204\1\.cp\swt-win32-3659.dll
0x00000000fdc60000 - 0x00000000fdcf8000     C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x0000000077480000 - 0x00000000775da000     C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
0x0000000077d20000 - 0x0000000077d23000     C:\Windows\system32\Normaliz.dll
0x00000000775e0000 - 0x00000000777ef000     C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
0x00000000777f0000 - 0x000000007793d000     C:\Windows\system32\urlmon.dll
0x00000000fb3c0000 - 0x00000000fb3d8000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x00000000056e0000 - 0x00000000056fe000     C:\Users\ASHISH\Downloads\Technology\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\204\1\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-3659.dll
0x00000000fb640000 - 0x00000000fb856000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7600.17007_none_2b47185a719d6182\gdiplus.dll
0x00000000fb050000 - 0x00000000fb17a000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x0000000008800000 - 0x0000000008831000     C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\btkeyind.dll
0x00000000fb860000 - 0x00000000fb98c000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
0x00000000f6de0000 - 0x00000000f6faa000     C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
0x00000000fbb90000 - 0x00000000fbbd3000     C:\Windows\system32\DUser.dll
0x00000000fb540000 - 0x00000000fb632000     C:\Windows\system32\DUI70.dll
0x00000000f3b50000 - 0x00000000f3ba4000     C:\Windows\system32\oleacc.dll
0x00000000fd480000 - 0x00000000fd494000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x00000000f61b0000 - 0x00000000f61c1000     C:\Users\ASHISH\Downloads\Technology\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\42\1\.cp\jWinHttp-1.0.0.dll
0x00000000f8f60000 - 0x00000000f8fcf000     C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x00000000f8ef0000 - 0x00000000f8f54000     C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll
0x00000000fa5f0000 - 0x00000000fa601000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x00000000fa5d0000 - 0x00000000fa5e8000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000000006bee0000 - 0x000000006bf04000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\sunec.dll
0x00000000f8450000 - 0x00000000f8457000     C:\Windows\system32\msimg32.dll
0x00000000f3bb0000 - 0x00000000f4618000     C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll
0x00000000fd3e0000 - 0x00000000fd472000     C:\Windows\system32\SXS.DLL
0x00000000fd370000 - 0x00000000fd3c7000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x0000000060040000 - 0x000000006113c000     C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.dll
0x00000000fd0b0000 - 0x00000000fd0bb000     C:\Windows\System32\Secur32.dll
0x00000000fd330000 - 0x00000000fd355000     C:\Windows\system32\SSPICLI.DLL
0x00000000fbc40000 - 0x00000000fbc6d000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x00000000fdc00000 - 0x00000000fdc50000     C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x00000000fb480000 - 0x00000000fb48e000     C:\Windows\system32\msimtf.dll
0x00000000f5b80000 - 0x00000000f5bba000     C:\Windows\system32\msls31.dll
0x00000000fd980000 - 0x00000000fdb57000     C:\Windows\system32\setupapi.dll
0x00000000fd830000 - 0x00000000fd866000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x00000000fd550000 - 0x00000000fd56a000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00000000ec8c0000 - 0x00000000ec9a2000     C:\Windows\system32\d2d1.dll
0x00000000eab40000 - 0x00000000eacbd000     C:\Windows\system32\DWrite.dll
0x00000000f70e0000 - 0x00000000f7187000     C:\Windows\system32\dxgi.dll
0x00000000fd680000 - 0x00000000fd6ba000     C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x00000000fd6c0000 - 0x00000000fd826000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x00000000fd540000 - 0x00000000fd54f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x00000000f72d0000 - 0x00000000f7304000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d10_1.dll
0x00000000f7190000 - 0x00000000f71e5000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d10_1core.dll
0x00000000f4d60000 - 0x00000000f4d9b000     C:\Windows\system32\MLANG.dll
0x00000000fad50000 - 0x00000000fadb2000     C:\Windows\system32\RASAPI32.dll
0x00000000fabe0000 - 0x00000000fabfc000     C:\Windows\system32\rasman.dll
0x00000000fabc0000 - 0x00000000fabd1000     C:\Windows\system32\rtutils.dll
0x00000000ea830000 - 0x00000000ea96d000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d10.dll
0x00000000f3ae0000 - 0x00000000f3b2b000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d10core.dll
0x00000000f89d0000 - 0x00000000f89d9000     C:\Windows\system32\sensapi.dll
0x00000000ea070000 - 0x00000000ea2a8000     C:\Windows\System32\jscript9.dll
0x000000006b810000 - 0x000000006b8db000     C:\Windows\System32\jscript.dll
0x000000006b7c0000 - 0x000000006b80a000     C:\Windows\System32\Dxtrans.dll
0x00000000faef0000 - 0x00000000faf09000     C:\Windows\System32\ATL.DLL
0x00000000f6270000 - 0x00000000f627e000     C:\Windows\system32\ddrawex.dll
0x00000000ec7c0000 - 0x00000000ec8b1000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x00000000f6230000 - 0x00000000f6238000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x000000006a5c0000 - 0x000000006a632000     C:\Windows\System32\Dxtmsft.dll
0x000000000ff70000 - 0x000000000fffc000     C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\btncopy.dll
0x00000000f7ea0000 - 0x00000000f7f20000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x00000000fcff0000 - 0x00000000fd013000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x00000000f8370000 - 0x00000000f837f000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x00000000faec0000 - 0x00000000faecb000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x0000000071c10000 - 0x0000000071c20000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseStub.dll
0x0000000071b40000 - 0x0000000071bbb000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseSVN.dll
0x00000000f7ad0000 - 0x00000000f7e9c000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libsvn_tsvn.dll
0x00000000719b0000 - 0x00000000719db000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libapr_tsvn.dll
0x0000000071780000 - 0x00000000717c1000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libaprutil_tsvn.dll
0x00000000f7ac0000 - 0x00000000f7ad0000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\intl3_tsvn.dll
0x00000000f7aa0000 - 0x00000000f7aba000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libsasl.dll
0x00000000716e0000 - 0x0000000071778000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP100.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xms40m -Xmx384m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
java_command: C:\Users\ASHISH\Downloads\Technology\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -showsplash -launcher C:\Users\ASHISH\Downloads\Technology\eclipse\eclipse.exe -name Eclipse --launcher.library C:\Users\ASHISH\Downloads\Technology\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222\eclipse_1312.dll -startup C:\Users\ASHISH\Downloads\Technology\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar -exitdata 112c_58 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -vm C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xms40m -Xmx384m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar C:\Users\ASHISH\Downloads\Technology\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;ommonProgramFiles\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\HP SimplePass Identity Protection\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\HP SimplePass Identity Protection\;C:\Users\ASHISH\Downloads\software\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\Users\ASHISH\Downloads\Technology\open-source\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Users\ASHISH\Downloads\Technology\installations\gradle-1.0-rc-3/bin;
USERNAME=ASHISH
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7600 

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 37 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 3987312k(1328476k free), swap 7972720k(4857692k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.1-b03) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_05-b05), built on May 15 2012 18:09:30 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Sun Jul 01 19:30:56 2012
elapsed time: 108 seconds
```

Please let me know if someone got the similar problem and its resolution

Comment: What version of eclipse ? Have you imported JUnit library ?

Comment: What do you mean by crashing?

Comment: eclipse 3.7.2, using projects junit lib, junit 4.1

Comment: reinstalling eclipse didn't help